# Why is writing an "Update" section in an SO question frowned upon?

Tags: discussion, edits

A practice I used to follow commonly accross the Stack Exchanges is the inclusion of an "Update", like in this [example](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/9506/how-do-i-pitch-a-message-for-a-fraternity-election) from the Interpersonal Skills SE:

> ## Update 2/6/2018
>
> I won the election! What worked for me is described in the Selected answer of this question.
>
> ## Conundrum
>
> ...[text follows]

I understand that one can look at the edit history of a question and find the reasoning for each edit.  However, I included this section as a courtesy to the reader in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50090059/does-two-phase-locking-apply-to-each-transaction-or-the-schedule-as-a-whole), but was later asked to remove this section.  Granted the latter question had many (and probably still has) glaring issues, but I was curious as to why the "Update" section was pointed out in particular.

Why, in SO in particular, is adding an update section in a question frowned upon, even as a facilitator to another reader?

Comment: Related: [What is the etiquette for modifying posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11474/what-is-the-etiquette-for-modifying-posts)

Comment: Also, if you're asking about a system-wide policy, then perhaps you should be asking this on the system-wide meta site: [meta.stackexchange.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: While I do reference another stack exchange, I was asked to remove the section on this stack exchange, not on the IPS exchange.  Hence why I asked specifically in this meta.

Comment: Some updates really are best as updates (e.g. when the question changes direction because a partial fix was found). However, in most cases, they are just additional information that has been requested in the comments, in which case it is not important to mark it as an update. When editing old questions, I often find myself collapsing down old "edit" and "update" remarks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> Why, in SO in particular, is adding an update section in a question frowned upon, even as a facilitator to another reader?

Because it is not really a facilitator.

Firstly, keep in mind that questions here are optimised for long-term value. Someone else reading the question a couple years from now will find little interest in the precise details of how your question evolved to its final form. From that perspective, it is clearer to incorporate the content of your edits as seamlessly as possible.

Secondly, even if we are concerned with the short term -- that is, your question being read by the folks helping you shape it and/or writing answers in the immediate aftermath of it being posted -- separate sections for edits don't make things clearer. If you want to make someone else aware that you performed an edit they suggested, you can ping them in a comment pointing it out. Furthermore, if anyone needs to check exactly what has changed in your question, it is just a question of looking at the edit history.